# mongodb $lookup 3 level nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongo and struggling mightily with the following.
In my mongodb database, there are 3 collections and structured as below.

lv1:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58650f1abbf1cd8804d0abde"), 
    "name": "lv1_aaa"
}
```

lv2:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ba45de41e78c7eb3fdfbfa6"), 
    "lv1_id": ObjectId("58650f1abbf1cd8804d0abde"), 
    "name": "lv2_bbb"
}
```

lv3:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ba45de41e78c7eb3fdfbfa6"), 
    "lv1_id": ObjectId("58650f1abbf1cd8804d0abde"),
    "lv2_id": ObjectId("58d8c3e1bbf1cd7436117bd6"), 
    "name": "lv3_ccc"
}
```

How can I get a data structure below use $lookup

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("58650f1abbf1cd8804d0abde"), 
        "name": "lv1_aaa",
        "children": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5ba45de41e78c7eb3fdfbfa6"), 
                "lv1_id": ObjectId("58650f1abbf1cd8804d0abde"), 
                "name": "lv2_bbb",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "_id": ObjectId("5ba45de41e78c7eb3fdfbfa6"), 
                        "lv1_id": ObjectId("58650f1abbf1cd8804d0abde"),
                        "lv2_id": ObjectId("58d8c3e1bbf1cd7436117bd6"), 
                        "name": "lv3_ccc"
                    },
                    ......
                ]
            },
            ......
        ]
    },
    ......
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.lv1.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { _id: 1 } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "lv2",
    "let": { "lv1_id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$sort": { index: 1 } },
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$lv1_id", "$$lv1_id" ] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "lv3",
        "let": { "lv2_id": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$sort": { index: 1 } },
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$lv2_id", "$$lv2_id" ] } } }
        ],
        "as": "children"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "children"
  }}
]);
```

Comment: Good!!! It works! Thank you very much @Anthony Winzlet. One more question, if I want to sort lv1 by  lv1._id, sort lv2 by lv2.index, and sort lv3 by lv3.index, then How can I do?

Comment: use `$sort` in each pipeline. `{$sort:{_id:1}}`

Comment: Ok, now $sort works. I've edit the answer :) Thanks again!